# Unable to locate problem in code/makefile--> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, makefile, header, c89

Obtaining a clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 when running makefile. Specifically when trying to create an executable:

```
gcc powers.c -Wall -pedantic -ansi -c
gcc bounds.o powers.o -o pracTwo
duplicate symbol '_power' in:
    bounds.o
    powers.o
```

Makefile:

```
pracTwo: bounds.o powers.o
    gcc bounds.o powers.o -o pracTwo

bounds.o : bounds.c macros.h
    gcc bounds.c -Wall -pedantic -ansi -c

powers.o : powers.c
    gcc powers.c -Wall -pedantic -ansi -c

clean: 
    rm -f pracTwo bounds.o powers.o
```

Expected result, 2 .o files created (bounds.o and powers.o) then they are linked together to make a pracTwo executable. Tried looking through the my files however unable to locate the problem?

Here are the headers of the .c files:
bounds.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "macros.h"

void intCheck();
void doubleCheck();
void charCheck();
```

And powers.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int power();
```

And here is the header file:

```
#ifndef MACROS_H
#define MACROS_H

#include "powers.c"
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE

#define BETWEEN (n<lower) || (n>upper)

#endif
```

Unsure what the issue is, cannot locate any error of the code. Unsure what duplicate symbol '_power' in: means.

Comment: `#include "powers.c"` You should not include C source files but only headers. Whatever you define in `powers.c` will be defined in any other source that happens to include it as well.

Comment: "Unsure what duplicate symbol '_power' in: means." That is very straight forward. It means you define one symbol in multiple places. Which you do because you compile `powers.c` and also files that include `powers.c`. Every symbol with external linkage should only be defined once.

Comment: Put your declarations in your `.h` files.  Put your definitions in your `.c` files.  Only include `.h` files.  Then you won't have problems like this.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks so much, this happened to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you include `powers.c` in `bounds.c` and link both `bounds.o` and `power.o` you end up with the same symbol linked twice. The code only includes declaration so I was not able to reproduce the error as my gcc complained about `power` not `_power` on my system.

I suggest you don't include the .c file and rely on just linking (`power.o`).  You may also be able to declare the function static to make it file local.

Unrelated, identifiers that start with `_` are reserved (7.1.3) so it's advisable that you don't use that in your code.

`BETWEEN` should probably be:

```
#define BETWEEN (n<lower) && (n>upper)
```

and you may want to use a function-like macro instead with the arguments passed in:

```
#define BETWEEN(lower, n, upper) ((n)<(lower)) && ((n)>(upper))
```